# Can someone suggest synonyms custom-meta-fields -> custom-field ?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm pretty sure both are the same, but my score is not enough to suggest the shorter one as a synonym to the longer one:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/custom-meta-fields/synonyms

And while browsing so, I found it funny, that themes/theme is synonym-ed but plugins/plugin still isn't: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only three questions no one has considerable [score in that tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/custom-meta-fields/topusers).

PS plugins-plugin now active.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and took care of this.